# WebApi: QueryString-Parameter is routing-relevant

Tags: asp.net-web-api, query-string

I have a methoth in my web api like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string path)
{
}
```

This is the corresponding URL:

```
http://server/web/api/controller?path='param'
```

But I want this query-string parameter optional.
I expect, if there is no query-string parameter, the string 'path' should be null.

But this is not working...
I have to create another method (otherwise the 'method' is not found)

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
```

Is there no other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try providing a default value and explicitly stating it is from the Uri.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri]string path = null)
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be the best/only way.